# Adding a Progress Bar to Parallel Code (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I have a list that can be evaluated in parallel. Each individual evaluation doesn't take that long, but there are many of them (1 million, for example). I'm using the following [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.2.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html). The plan is split the list into chunks and run them in parallel. I have something like the following that works:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.DeepSeq

-- Imagine this being slightly more expensive
kindaExpensiveComputation :: Int -> [Int]
kindaExpensiveComputation n = replicate n 42

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let n = 1000000
    let args = replicate n 20
    let chunkSize = n `div` 10
    let result = force $ withStrategy (parListChunk chunkSize rseq) . map kindaExpensiveComputation $ args
    -- do stuff with result here
    -- end program
```

I would like to add a progress bar to this so I can keep track of how much of the list has been done. My instinct was to try something like the following:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.DeepSeq
import System.ProgressBar

-- Imagine this being slightly more expensive
kindaExpensiveComputation :: ProgressBar s -> Int -> IO [Int]
kindaExpensiveComputation pb n = do
    let res = replicate n 42
    incProgress pb 1
    return res

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let n = 1000000
    let args = replicate n 20
    let chunkSize = n `div` 10
    pb <- newProgressBar defStyle 10 (Progress 0 n ())
    let result = force $ withStrategy (parListChunk chunkSize rseq) . map (kindaExpensiveComputation pb) $ args
    -- do stuff with result here
    -- end program
```

But `force` doesn't seem to be able to handle `IO`. I've tried a couple other things, but whatever I try evaluates the list of `IO [Int]` in parallel but not the actual contents of the `IO`. I see that the parallel library has some functions like `withStrategyIO`, although I'm not sure how to use it or if it's what I'm looking for.

I think my understanding of how Haskell evaluates expressions is causing my confusion, so any pointers on that would be helpful as well.

Comment: “But `force` doesn't seem to be able to handle `IO`” — It handles `IO` just fine, but this doesn't mean what you seem to think it does. Forcing an `IO` action merely brings it to normal form, it does _not_ execute any actual IO. If you want to distribute IO over multiple threads then what you're dealing with is _concurrency_ rather than parallelism.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I'm not really doing any ```IO```. The only part of the computation that's doing ```IO``` is displaying the progress bar. I really do want parallelism and not concurrency.

Comment: Displaying progress _is_ IO. It needs to write the progress percentage to console or draw it in a window or whatever you have there. That's definitely IO. It makes changes to the outside world. So if you want to report progress in the middle of the computation, then that computation becomes IO.

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying the slow part of the computation is not the I/O, so I do want parallelism and not concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe GHC currently does not expose any functionality for observing (in `IO`, obviously) the evaluation progress of parallel computations. You will need to use concurrency in the form of `forkIO` and friends (or a library that wraps them like the `async` package) instead.

Comment: `IO` can drive parallel evaluation, and thereby wait for it to complete.

Comment: @dfeuer And? As far as I can tell, that's not relevant to OP's goals. A progress bar that jumps from "haven't started yet" to "all done" and never shows progress in between isn't very useful.

Comment: I haven't looked in detail as the OP's situation, but you can have a list such that forcing a cons will 1. Await the completion of one parallel computation and 2. Spark the evaluation of another one. You can set the number of sparks to have open at once in this arrangement. I'm pretty sure there's a function for this sort of pattern in `C.P.S.`, but I can't check the details right now.

Comment: I think it's `parBuffer`.